# I can't run my C++ program with this error "undefined reference to WinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c++

I have code with the C++ language:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("halo");
}
```

and i have error

```
C:\Users\retno\Documents>g++ -o prog halo.cpp
C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function main':
C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v3-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: I have trouble believing this is the exact code. This is not cpp first off.

Comment: This is not cpp? But i thought that cstdio be able to run printf right?

Comment: Try <stdio.h>. Not cpp still... You would utilize <iostream> and std::cout << "halo" << std::endl;

Comment: @ReniSetyaningsih `cstdio` is indeed the standard c++ library header equivalent for standard C stdio.h, and yes, you can use it if you want to access the likes of things like `printf`. There's nothing wrong with that. The problem is your build configuration. You're building your application as a Windows native app, not a *console* app.  You may try `-mconsole` as one of your build switches

Comment: @WhozCraig so basically, i can run the program, cant i?

Comment: Yes. as I said, it's a subsystem targeting thing. It *appears* you're default targeting native win apps (don't ask me how, I'm a clang guy :-). Native win apps hit WinMain as their user startup point, not `main`. If your prod around on this site, searching for things like `mingw console app` etc. you can probably get the exact information you need. It is for-certain doable, so just peck around awhile; you'll find it.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry, what's the keyword of '-mconsole'? (same with my prediction that i have a probelm in my path)

Comment: A command line switch. You know : `g++ -mconsole -o prog halo.cpp`

Comment: oh i see, thanks a lot for helping 